# How to show 2 products per column on mobile view in Woocommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, smartphone

i have issue with showing 2 products per column in smartphone view. I tryed this CSS, to customize the look, but it show now all products into one row. [URL](http://bossiopro.com/) to shop.

```
@media (max-width: 480px)  {

#dhvc_woo_fc7928715c .dhvc-woo-masonry-list .dhvc-woo-masonry-item {
 float: left;
  width: 50%;
 }
}
```

im using Visual Composer and DHVC Woocommerce Products Layouts
 to get that look. Currently is showing like this:

[image]

and want to make like this:

[image]

what is wrong in my CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, your first "single column" media query is `767px` wide, not `480px`.

That said, there should be an option somewhere in your DHVC Woocommerce Products Layouts, either in a settings page or in the JavaScript itself that controls the layout options like that.

Edit: According to the plugin page, you may have better luck with the `Grid` layout option instead of Masonry: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-products-layouts/7384574#item-description__features

Currently, the **reason your CSS isn't taking effect** is because you have DHVC set to using a **Masonry** layout, which sets each element to `position: absolute` and adjusts the `top` and `left` values accordingly, so `display: inline-block`, `float: left;` and similar faux-column tricks won't work.

If you can't find the option in the DHVC settings or the JavaScript, you'll need to take it to the plugin developer for further assistance.

Edit: Like I said, I can almost guarantee the option you're looking for is in the DHVC options. Using the Masonry option makes "making it like you want via CSS" much more of a hack and imho, ugly.

If you're **adamant** about using just CSS (despite there assuredly being options to change the behavior in the `/wp-admin/` settings page, and the developer providing premium support) - you'll need to remove the height Masonry sets on the parent container, and override inline styles on the items. Something like this will get you started ... Again please consider using the built in options or ask the plugin developer before using this, it will probably cause you or the next person in charge of the site quite a headache later down the line.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    /* Masonry sets an absolute defined px based height, overwrite that */
    .dhvc-woo-row-fluid.dhvc-woo-masonry-list {
        height: auto !important;
    }

    /* Masonry sets absolute, top, and left, overwrite those
       as well as setting them to have a small gutter */
    .dhvc-woo-item.dhvc-woo-masonry-item {
        position: relative !important;
        top: auto !important;
        left: auto !important;
        width: 50%;
        width: calc( 50% - 10px );
        float: left;
    }

    /* Scooch every second item over 10px */
    .dhvc-woo-item.dhvc-woo-masonry-item:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: No way how to make it like i want? i meen via CSS?

Comment: Did you read through the answer? It's a premium plugin so I can't help you with the options, but I'm sure there's an option in there to adjust what you want. Using just CSS to fix it will be a hack because you'll need overly complicated selectors, and `Masonry` works with absolute positioning and pixel based heights which makes "undoing" it with CSS quite tedious. I've updated the answer for a hack of a CSS solution - please look through the options or reach out to the DHVC plugin dev before using it though.